# Converting Email ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

I made a script to get email body from PIPE. Here is what I got:

```
--_a09b8441-38d7-411d-93d3-19fe256fc2d3_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

isto=2C isto =E9 um t=E9ste! :D
```

After using regex, I got only this:

```
isto=2C isto =E9 um t=E9ste! :D
```

Anyway, the email sended was:

```
isto, isto é um téste! :D
```

I already tried to convert this with iconv, but it doesn't change. I need to get what was sended with the accents working from what I receive.

Please help me. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found how to do this. Code:

```
$message='isto=2C isto =E9 um t=E9ste! :D';
$message=quoted_printable_decode($message)
$message=iconv('iso-8859-1','utf-8', $message);
```

Output:

```
isto, isto é um téste! :D
```